# Swift Alamofire Escape a JSON

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire

I am working with swift Alamofire, but i had an issue, i want pass data to the server but the server required escaped JSON string, like this

```
{\"status\":1,\"id\":\"1bcc3331b09d32f7439ad9d5f2acfb35\",\"progress\":[{\"airline_code\":\"SRI\",\"ctr\":0,\"rate\":5,\"state\":1,\"data\":null}]}
```

but I have this data from the response:

```
{"status":1,"id":"1bcc3331b09d32f7439ad9d5f2acfb35","progress":[{"airline_code":"SRI","ctr":0,"rate":5,"state":1,"data":null}]}
```

how can I convert JSON to escaped JSON like that,

I have tried this online converter 
[Converter Escape JSON](https://codebeautify.org/json-escape-unescape)

and its works perfect, how can I escape like that in swift Xcode.

update complete json (look inside feed: )

```
{
   "flight_child":"0",
   "child":"[]",
   "depart_hidden_transit":"0",
   "depart_adult_surcharge":"0",
   "depart_flight":"[{\"airlineCode\":\"LIO\",\"arriveCity\":\"Jakarta Soekarno Hatta\",\"arriveDate\":\"2018-04-28\",\"arriveDatetime\":\"2018-04-28 20:05\",\"arrivePort\":\"CGK\",\"arriveTime\":\"20:05\",\"arriveTimezone\":7.0,\"departCity\":\"Yogyakarta\",\"departDate\":\"2018-04-28\",\"departDatetime\":\"2018-04-28 18:50\",\"departPort\":\"JOG\",\"departTime\":\"18:50\",\"departTimezone\":7.0,\"flightNumber\":\"JT 555\",\"stopCount\":0}]",
   "auth_mode":"",
   "flight_infant":"0",
   "flight_to":"CGK",
   "flight_return":"",
   "depart_child_discount":"0",
   "infant":"[]",
   "depart_choice":"d3ea46551c769f462c3e1a4dd25c933d",
   "depart_child_surcharge":"0",
   "version_code":"3",
   "contact_email":"mul@gmai.oc",
   "contact_name":"Mulia RIfai",
   "adult":"[[\"Mr\",\"Muhammad Fuad\",null,null,\"0\",null,null,null,null,null]]",
   "flight_trip":"oneway",
   "flight_adult":"1",
   "depart_adult_discount":"0",
   "contact_phone":"0972312",
   "depart_carrier":"LIO",
   "client_password":"arena123",
   "depart_infant_discount":"0",
   "depart_infant_surcharge":"0",
   "client_username":"androidarena",
   "flight_depart":"2018-05-03",
   "feed":"{\"status\":1,\"id\":\"1bcc3331b09d32f7439ad9d5f2acfb35\",\"progress\":[{\"airline_code\":\"SRI\",\"ctr\":0,\"rate\":5,\"state\":1,\"data\":null}]}",
   "contact_title":"Mr.",
   "flight_from":"JOG",
   "depart_class":"eco",
   "device_id":"123456789011123"
}
```

Comment: so your server wants the json in string format!!!!? *sigh anyways, what does your API call look like?

Comment: yea because its json inside json, so the server need escaped json, @staticVoidMan

Comment: ok, share some more details about your API; example URL and example payload (entire payload, not just the json-inside-json part)

Comment: @staticVoidMan see update question

Comment: ok, you'll get a solution soon but I would rather suggest you get the backend guys to stop working with stringified jsons. that's just so... dirty!!

Comment: @staticVoidMan hahaha, thats beyond my authority XD

Comment: @themasmul Just inform authority. Once you've done the work.(ie testing and live in app store). if then they realize and change the format(ease for them), you have to do rework.(Change the working Code + Testing + App update).

Comment: In this, I think you have to set the JSON string manually for the particular keys. ex. Instead of  rootParams["feed"] = [ Dictinoary value] ...,  `rootParams["feed"] = convertIntoJson(dict : feedDictionaryValue)` Then pass to alamofire.

Comment: @themasmul and... what does your Alamofire code look like right now? Do you send the entire object back or just `feed`? Do you have to do the same for `depart_flight` & `adult` too?

Answer (score 0):

Even though this should be fixed by the server. A nasty hack would be to first stringify your json that should be passed as the string and then replacing the occurrence of double quotation with \".

```
let dic = ["status":1,
               "id":"1bcc3331b09d32f7439ad9d5f2acfb35",
               "progress":[["airline_code":"SRI","ctr":0,"rate":5,"state":1,"data":nil]
    ]

        ] as [String : Any]

    if let json = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dic, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.init(rawValue: 0)) {
        if let str = String(data: json, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)?.replacingOccurrences(of: "\"", with: "\\\"") {
            print(str)
        }
    }
```

Result:

```
{\"id\":\"1bcc3331b09d32f7439ad9d5f2acfb35\",\"status\":1,\"progress\":[{\"state\":1,\"airline_code\":\"SRI\",\"data\":null,\"ctr\":0,\"rate\":5}]}
```

Comment: nooo, the server cant handle json with space like that, only one lined json,

Comment: @themasmul Just change the writing options and you will get single line string. I will update the answer.